# How can I measure the width of a string rendering via tkFont without creating a window first?

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter

I can do the measure of text with tkFont, but I don't want a root window --> tk.Tk()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did mean to ask: “How can I measure the width of a string rendering via `tkFont` without creating a window first?”

An the answer is: you can’t. Tk needs it’s root instance to do drawing and such.

you can however create it, measure your text, and immediately dispose it via `.delete()`. This is so fast that the window doesn’t appear for me.

Comment: No problem :D i hope i’m right, though, and there isn’t a fancy way to do it. (or actually i hope i’m wrong and you get what you wanted. i doubt it, though). I edited the answer, btw.

Answer (score 5):

Now I have this, and it works

```
root = tk.Tk()
font = tkFont.Font(family=fn, size=fs)
w, h = (font.measure(text), font.metrics("linespace"))
root.destroy()
```